# Load image to imageview android from rest service on asp.net core

Tags: android, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

How i can load image to imageview on android from rest service on asp.net core.
At asp.net core i have controller MyController and method:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]  
[ApiController]  
public class MyController  : ControllerBase  
{  
    // GET api/values  
    [HttpGet]  
    public IActionResult Get(string type)  
    {  
        Byte[] b;  
        if(type == null)  
        {  
            return NotFound();  
        }  

        Image image = DrawText("My Example: " + type, new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 15), Color.DarkBlue, Color.Cornsilk);  
        b = ImageToByteArray(image);  //Simulate loading images from the database

        return File(b, "image/jpeg");  
    } 

    public byte[] ImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)  
    {              
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();  
            imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);  
            return ms.ToArray();              
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find answer: Image wiew must put jpg or bmp format, but not jpeg